# Calculate years of seniority on termination date OR if blank Today's date

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, date

I would like a calculation that gives the number of years between 2 dates (Hire Date & Termination Date) but if Termination Date is blank I would like it to use today's date to calculate how many years of service.

I would like the answer to show in years including partition years.  I cannot get it to do it and not round up or down.  I would like it to show 1.2 years for example.

For SharePoint Online.

```
 =IF(ISBLANK([Termination Date]),DATEDIF([Hire Date], Today(),"y"),DATEDIF([Hire Date], [Termination Date],"y"))
```

Would I be able to show years and months?  Such as "6 yrs, 11 mths"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below formula. In this formula I have considered decimal point as month so in case of 2 years and 11 months it will display 2.11

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(ISBLANK([Termination Date]),DATEDIF([Hire Date],NOW(),"y"),DATEDIF([Hire Date],[Termination Date],"y")),"  yrs, ",IF(ISBLANK([Termination Date]),DATEDIF([Hire Date],NOW(),"ym"),DATEDIF([Hire Date],[Termination Date],"ym")), " mths")
```

Below is the screen shot for column creation:

[image]

It will give below result in my case.

[image]

Comment: That works thank you!!  Is there a way I can show the answer as " 2 yrs, 11 mths"

Comment: I keep trying this but I get an error each time.  Exact same parameters - calculated field set to single line of text and copy and pasted formula.

Comment: GOT IT!!  In the formula i copped above there are 2 equal signs at the beginning.  Thank you!!

Comment: Corrected formula